# yaml equals to equalsIgnoreCase

Tags: java, spring, yaml

I have api.yaml inside the file I create Enum value

```
Language:
      type: string
      enum:
      - ar
      - en
      - fr
```

The file below generated, in fromValue method I need change equals to equalsIgnoreCase when I changed it manually and resave the api.yaml file the change disappeared

```
public enum Language {
      AR("ar"),
      EN("en"),
      FR("fr");
      private String value;
      Language(String value) {
        this.value = value;
      }
      @Override
      @JsonValue
      public String toString() {
        return String.valueOf(value);
      }
      @JsonCreator
      public static Language fromValue(String text) {
        for (Language b : Language.values()) {
          if (String.valueOf(b.value).equals(text)) {
            return b;
          }
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unexpected value '" + text + "'");
      }
    }
```

Comment: What library/command are you using to generate the code from the yaml definition?

Answer (score 0):

Enums are always going to be case insensitive from the generator. There are a couple of options though. You can use a regex pattern in your api definition instead of the enum:

https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/EnumUtils.html

Or you might be able to take a look at these properties in Spring though I'm not sure it will help with your generated code:

`spring.jackson.mapper.accept-case-insensitive-enums=true`

Though that would only be for automatically deserialized data.